# Write custom pixels/vram in Unity3D

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, texture2d, vram

I have been thinking about this for a while. I know we can write to our own textures with setpixels, but i also know this is a really slow method that would start dropping framerates below 30 just being there. (Due to the sync with the videocard that happens after.)

So either i am using the wrong method, or doing it wrong. But i cannot find a proper way to write my own vram to a texture or directly to a camera.

Long story short, if i were to build like an emulator inside unity, and i wanted this emulator to run on either camera pixel by pixel or just on a texture inside unity. How would i get this going without slowing my framerate to a crawl on most devices?

Are shaders an option? If so, please point me in a direction since i never made those on my own just yet.

Comment: As far as I know Unity can't do this. Unity is not ment for drawing stuff by your self.

Comment: But there are tools that allow you to draw lines and such (like debug rays, but then at runtime) i suppose those do something like that, right?

Comment: Drawing Lines is possible, but they are 1px wide, so drawing an image with them will not be possible, or much worse than set pixel.

Comment: While an interesting discussion question, it's simply not suitable for SO. Perhaps try gamedev.com or forum.unity3d

Comment: They hardly work though, it is at least programming related. I am looking for a proper method/addon/library to achieve a screen in screen when i have my own code generated video output. Are rendertextures better maybe?